# exclude - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

here build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.2")) {
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-core"
    }

    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("junit:junit")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core")
}
```

And it's work just fine.

But I want to do same in build.gradle.kts

build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
      implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.2")) {
        exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-core")
    }

    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl")

   
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}
```

But rise error:

Script compilation error:

```
  Line 28:         exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-core")
                   ^ None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
                       public open fun exclude(vararg p0: Class<*>!): Categories.CategoryFilter! defined in org.gradle.internal.impldep.org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.CategoryFilter
                       public open fun exclude(p0: Boolean, vararg p1: Class<*>!): Categories.CategoryFilter! defined in org.gradle.internal.impldep.org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.CategoryFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can remove that call to `exclude`.

When you use [`enforcedPlatform`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl/-dependency-handler/enforced-platform.html?query=abstract%20fun%20enforcedPlatform(notation:%20Any):%20Dependency) you are declaring a dependency on a [Maven BOM](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import) which doesn't add dependencies *per se*, it just specifies versions for them. So it won't add Logback as a dependency (which appears to be your desired outcome), and in turn you don't need to exclude it.

In the Kotlin DSL, calling `exclude` for a platform dependency is no longer a valid call<sup>1</sup>. It has, then, has removed some functionality from Gradle.

I don't believe this is a big problem though. Using `exclude` in the Groovy way appears useful if you want to use Logback (or another dependency specified in a BOM) but you didn't want the version specified in the BOM. However, in such a case you could use `platform` rather than `enforcedPlatform` to register the BOM and you could go on to choose the version you wanted (which would then have precedence).

---

<sup>1</sup>On a code level, using `enforcedPlatform` changes the receiver in the closure from [`ModuleDependency`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api.artifacts/-module-dependency/index.html?query=interface%20ModuleDependency%20:%20Dependency,%20HasConfigurableAttributes%3CSELF%3E) to a plain `Dependency`, meaning that the extension function [`exclude`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/exclude.html), an extension of `ModuleDependency`, is no longer available in that scope.